# Check if friends from array PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a news feed type script. Each user has an array of userid's that are considered friends, and I'm trying to only display info from the database if the userid is part of the current users friendslist. It displays all results from the database, and I'm not sure why.

If anyone could show me a better way to do this, or at least point out what I've done wrong it would be appreciated!

```
include('config.php');

$query2 = "SELECT id, userid, action, date FROM newsfeed ORDER BY date DESC"
or die("Query failed");
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_NUM)){
$id = $row[0];
$userid = $row[1];
$action = $row[2];
$date = $row[3];

if($userid != $myid){
    $areFriends = in_array($userid, $myfriends); //Check if friends
}

if($areFriends = 1){
    $query3 = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE `id` = '$userid'"
    or die("query failed");
    $result3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query3);
    while ($row = $result3->fetch_row()){
        $useridname = $row[0];
    }
    echo(" - ".$id." - ".$useridname." - ".$action."<br />");
    $areFriends = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: `if ( $areFriends )`, not `if ( $areFriends = 1 )` ...you're setting `$areFriends` to `1` every time which will always evaluate boolean `true`. Also consider using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and referencing cols as `$row['userid']`. Lastly, `$areFriends` is undefined iff `$userid != $myid`, consider setting `$areFriends = false;` before the comparison, otherwise you're subject to E_NOTICE messages.

Comment: In most social graphs, message are simply distributed to all friends. In other words if friend *x* updates his status, all his friends have some kind of personal feed (well an array of feed id's) and the id is added to all friends. At least that's how for instance BitBucket and GitHub work. A disadvantage is of course that when two people report they are friends, their feeds are not up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, the main problem is that when you say `if ($areFriends = 1)`, you're actually *setting* `areFriends` to 1, and then seeing whether 1 is true (which it always is).  So the quick fix would be to use `==` instead.

You could keep going, though, and simplify this code by getting rid of `$areFriends` altogether.  There's not really any point in it, if you're setting the variable and checking it immediately after.  Instead, just take what you want to do when `$userid` is in the friends list...and *do it then* rather than setting the flag.  Watch:

```
# If a user can't friend themselves, then even this `if` is unnecessary.
if($userid != $myid) {
    if (in_array($userid, $myfriends)) {
        $friend_query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE `id` = '$userid'";

        # fixed this for you, btw.  you want the `or ...` after the mysqli_query,
        # since that's what can fail.  :P
        $friend_result = mysqli_query($dbc, $friend_query)
          or die("query failed");

        # If you'll only have one row, use `if`.
        if (($friend = $friend_result->fetch_assoc())) {
            echo(" - $id - {$friend['username']} - $action<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

With `$areFriends` also goes the weirdness of that "if it's true, do stuff, then make it false" stuff.

You could improve things a lot more, though...but how depends a bit on where your array of friends is coming from.

- If it's in a properly normalized table, for example, you could simply do a join on the table.

  Let's say you had a `user_friends` table, for example, with `user_id` and `friend_id`.  Each row
  in the table basically says that user `user_id` has friended user `friend_id`.

  With such a table, you don't even have to pass the friends list.  You can just do an `INNER JOIN`
  on the table where the `user_id` column matches `$myid`.

  ```
  $myid = intval($myid); # no need to demonstrate sql injection :P
  $news_query = "
      SELECT news.id, u.username useridname, news.action, news.date
      FROM newsfeed news
        INNER JOIN user_friends friends ON friends.friend_id = news.userid
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = friends.friend_id
      WHERE friends.user_id = $myid
      ORDER BY news.date DESC
  ";
  ```
- If it's just an array you found on the side of the road somewhere, then you need to build the SQL to pass a list.

  ```
  $friend_ids = implode(', ', array_map('intval', $myfriends));
  $news_query = "
      SELECT news.id, u.username useridname, news.action, news.date
      FROM newsfeed news
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = news.userid
      WHERE news.userid IN ($friend_ids)
      ORDER BY news.date DESC
  ";
  ```

Either way, rather than going and querying a second time to find usernames, or skipping non-friends, you're fetching the columns you need -- and *only* the rows you need -- all at once.

Once you have that SQL, it's *trivial* to run through a query result and list stuff.  For example, with the friends table...

```
$myid = intval($myid); # no need to demonstrate sql injection :P
$news_query = "
    SELECT news.id, u.username useridname, news.action, news.date
    FROM newsfeed news
      INNER JOIN user_friends friends ON friends.friend_id = news.userid
      INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = friends.friend_id
    WHERE friends.user_id = $myid
    ORDER BY news.date DESC
";

$news_result = $dbc->query($news_query) or die("Query failed");
while (($news = $news_result->fetch_assoc())) {
    echo " - {$news['id']} - {$news['useridname']} - {$news['action']}<br />";
}
```

Aaaaaand *done*.  This code displays roughly the same thing as the entirety of what you have.  (The main potential output difference is what happens when `$myid` is on their own friends list.  This can be incorporated into the SQL, though.)

Basically the biggest things it's *not* doing are setting a bunch of variables, reexamining the friends list, or re-querying the database for usernames.  You don't need to do that anymore, cause the query already told MySQL exactly what rows and columns you want.

Comment: Thankyou for this. It's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm sort of confused though. In the database, under users, a friendslist for a user friends with id 4 would look like this `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"4";}`. I then have a separate table called newsfeed with id, userid, action and date. I'm not really sure of what to do at this point. Sorry for poor wording, I'm not great at explaining these things.

Comment: @user3010610: So the friends list is a serialized array.  In that case, you'd use the "array you found on the side of the road" method.  :)  It'd be better IMO to normalize your data and have a table linking users and their friends, for a number of reasons related to data integrity and separation of concerns...but to just make what's there work, you'd `unserialize` the field (which turns it back into an array), implode its values as described, and there's your `$friend_ids`.

Comment: Trying that method and keep getting query failed, I'm trying to wrap my head around the inner join. We covered it for about 5 minutes in class and it was definitely fuzzy. Do you have any ideas why I might be getting query failed? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm getting error Query failed: Table ****.user_friends doesn't exist

Comment: @user3010610: You'd need to actually *have* a table named `user_friends` in order to do a join on it.  If you don't have one, then use the code that builds the list from an array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make what I hope are a few safe assumptions.

- You only want items from friends and to ignore non-friends.
- Your newsfeed.userid is a foreign key to users.id and it is an INT value (or rather that it is intended to be even if it wasn't added as a formal constraint).

I would let the database do the work for you. This minimizes the CPU time, memory, network bandwidth (less calls to MySQL).

I would update your query to

```
$query = 'SELECT NF.id, NF.userid, U.username NF.action, NF.date '.
         'FROM newsfeed AS NF JOIN users AS U ON U.id=NF.userid '.
         'WHERE '.
         'NF.userid IN ('.implode(',', array_map('intval', $myfriends)).') '.
         'ORDER BY date DESC';
```

This reduces the number of calls to one and gets you only the information you are interested in.

A warning is that if the $myfriends array is very large, you could run into MySQL's maximum query length (depends on version and startup options).

Comment: Much better way of doing this, but I'm getting a syntax error with this and I can't wrap my head around why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your script is that you are setting $areFriend to 1 in every loop.

```
if ($areFriends = 1)    // If setting $areFriends to 1 is successful (so true)

if ($areFriends == 1)   // If $areFriends equals 1, or true

if ($areFriends === 1)  // If $areFriends equals 1 and only 1
```

A better way of doing your original query would be to just use a join and make use of `IN`.

Like so...

```
SELECT u.id as userId, u.username, n.id as newsId, n.action, n.date 
FROM newsfeed as n 
JOIN users as u on n.userId = u.id
WHERE
userId in (:myFriends) &&   // User id is in array of myfriend ids
userId != :myId             // User is not me
ORDER BY n.date DESC
```

This way your search will only result in actions by users with an id in your array of friends id's and you won't need to loop over that second array a bunch of times.

**EDIT**

As in @ErikNedwidek's answer (and comment below) you would need to add `implode(',', array_map('intval', $myfriends))` into the `IN` part as mysqli doesn't bind arrays to parameters.

Comment: bind_params() unfortunately will not accept an array. For integer values you can implode them and use array_map to make sure they are ints. For other values, you can use call_user_func_array(). Basically you create your callback to create the comma separated list and use mysqli_real_escape_string() on each item.

Comment: Yeah I looked at that and then removed that part. I've never used mysqli so I was kind of winging it with that one hoping it would work. Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your comparison differently; you are only checking if `$areFriends` exists. So it will always come back true if `$userid` is not equal to `$myid`.

Take a look at this simple example of one way to compare:

```
$myid = "1";     // hypothetical examples
$userid = "10";
$myfriends = array( 'friends' => array( 10, 3, 11, 33, 42));

if ($userid != $myid) {
    if (in_array($userid, $myfriends['friends'])) { // Check if friends
        $areFriends = "TRUE";
    } else {
        $areFriends = "FALSE";
    }
}

if ($areFriends == "TRUE") {
    echo "you are friends with id ".$userid;
} else {
    echo "you are not friends with id ".$userid;
}
```

it should shed some light on how to pick out the correct values and compare them.

Comment: Erm...no.  `in_array` returns a boolean, which will be either `true` if `$userid` is in `$myfriends['friends']`, or `false` if not (and, if true, is loosely equal to 1).  The problem is the `=` rather than `==`; the rest of the answer is just complicating things -- and in fact introduces a bug, since you never reset `$areFriends`.

Comment: You have taken my answer way out of context; not surprising though in the least.

Comment: The code is overcomplicated ("TRUE" and "FALSE" fix nothing whatsoever, and basically *require* using `if ($areFriends == 'TRUE')` rather than `if ($areFriends)`), and introduces bugs (it could say `"you are friends with id $myid"`, since you never reset `$areFriends`), and the explanation is incorrect as far as the OP's code is concerned (the OP was not checking, nor intending to check, whether `$areFriends` exists; the code was (long-windedly but legally, once the `=` becomes `==`) testing its truth value). If there is a context that'd change those facts, you really need to mention it.

Comment: I don't think you understand the code. Using `"you are friends with id $myid"` would indicate they are friends with themselves. So you're incorrect as far as your whole rant in concerned.

Comment: OK. say you have four posts.  One was posted by a friend, the next one by the user himself, the next by a non-friend, and the last by the user himself.  The first time through the loop, `$areFriends` will be set to `'TRUE'`.  The second time, since `$userid == $myid`, the code that would modify `$areFriends` won't run.  So `$areFriends == 'TRUE'`, and the code obediently echoes "You are friends with id $userid".  The third time through, `$areFriends` gets set to `'FALSE'`.  And the fourth time, again, `$userid == $myid`, so no change.  So now "you are *not* friends with id $userid".

Comment: But `$userid` is the same ID in both cases (as it is equal to `$myid`).  Since they contradict each other, at least one of those statements has to be incorrect.  (And that's even before mentioning the nonsense of someone being or not being their own friend, particularly when this status isn't even based on whether they're in their friends list.)

Comment: I was demonstrating a one time check; as if the person went to another persons profile and viewed it. I don't recall seeing anything about posts or looping through an entire friends list. I realize the code is not optimal, but it was done for a reason. I'm not here to program for someone — I'm here so they can learn something and I can too. If you have a better answer then why not post it? or at least show me where the sample I posted fails. I do take what you say into account, although it seems you interpret this quite differently.

Comment: I interpreted it as suggested changes to the OP's existing code, as would be expected when you use basically the same code structure, variable names, and everything.  If that wasn't your intent, then you really need to make that clearer in the answer.  Because the code would do a bunch of wrong things if it were just pasted in.

Comment: I hadn't posted an answer because the problem being asked about is already solved by the accepted answer...which also presented a couple of ideas about how to prevent the check altogether.  What i had to add wouldn't be worth a separate answer.  I'm reconsidering, though...

Comment: The question (originally) was asking "why does this function always return true?". In the example I mentioned it to be 'hypothetical'; I think the OP understood that. Just because an answer has been chosen as correct shouldn't stop you from posting a solution. I often wonder how many great answers are never revealed merely because of that reason (or timing).